# PHP - please check this is the correct way to return the INT from a SQL SELECT COUNT Query with PDO

Tags: php, sql, pdo, int

Please could you inform me if this is the correct way to execute the SQL count query to return an integer value using PHP.

I have only been learning PHP for 2 weeks so apologies if this is a noob question.

CODE:

```
include 'connection.php';

try {
    $results = $conn->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users");
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "unable to perform SQL Request";
    exit;
}

$result = $results->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM);

echo $result[0][0];
```

Comment: You can just do `$results->fetchColumn(0)` in this case

Comment: Along with the code also share the results/errors you are getting when you run the code.

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile that makes no sense for several reasons.

Comment: No he should not and that is terrible advice.

Comment: That is beyond horrible.

Comment: The TL;DR is @MasivuyeCokile: you are building a car factory, a solar panel company and a space exploration company just to buy a car. But in your case the car you build with all of the above is exactly the same car you could have already just bought from an existing car dealer.

Comment: Bad analogy. Building all those things would be actually beneficial. Selecting content of the entire table (which could have several millions of entries with 20+ rows) to get a row count is just stupid.

Answer (score 1):

it should be

```
include 'connection.php';
$result = $conn->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users")->fetchColumn();
echo $result;
```

Comment: Or even better yet `COUNT(key)`.

Comment: @PeeHaa your database is intelligent enough to use a key, if it exists.

Comment: Yes in most cases it should. I had some discussion about this very thing with somebody (from doctrine) a while back telling me there are some edge cases with that approach.

Comment: Wow that's clean... so basically I introduced an unnecessary extra step where as the Fetchcolumn method did everything I need.  Thanks guys really appreciate the help!

Comment: @JamesBrown and one more extra step with all that try-catch stuff. You may want to take a look at the [PDO tutorial](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#returntypes) I wrote for the explanation.

Comment: Thanks @your common sense much appreciated will check it out - thanks for the help!!!!